# Nuxt.js - Screen goes Blank

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I created a middleware to give page access base on role.

I am using the `nuxt auth module` to login user

I have three middleware

> checklogin.js

```
export default function ({ store, redirect, $auth }) {
  if ($auth.loggedIn) {
    return redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

> admin.js

```
export default function ({ $auth, redirect }) {
  const user = $auth.user
  if ((user.role !== 'admin') && (user.role !== 'super admin') && (user.role !== 'publisher')) {
    return redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

> publisher.js

```
export default function ({ store, redirect, $auth }) {
  if ($auth.user.role === 'publisher') {
    return redirect('/publishers')
  }
}
```

On my Page level, I added this

```
export default {
  middleware: ['auth', 'admin', 'publisher'],
```

It was all fine until I added the publisher middleware.

I check the console, I saw this error

> Error: Redirected when going from "/" to "/publishers" via a navigation guard.

> Actual behavior
> I want a `publisher` to only have access to the Publisher page on the dashboard, thus when a publisher login, it gets redirected to the publisher's page. The `admin` and `super admin` can access every other page.

Comment: Do you have a `$auth.user.role` when the middleware is run ? What is the actual error's behavior ? Shouldn't it be the page that you want him to redirect to ?

Comment: yes. I want a `publisher` to only have access to the Publisher page on the dashboard, thus when a publisher login, it gets redirected to the publisher's page. The `admin` and `super admin` can access every other page. @kissu

Comment: So: Do you have a $auth.user.role when the middleware is run ? What is the actual error's behavior ? Shouldn't it be the page that you want him to redirect to ?

Comment: Yes, I do have `$auth.user.role` when the middleware run. The actual error behavior is it doesn't get redirected. The page becomes non-responsive, keeps loading with a white blank screen.

Comment: Try to see the vue devtools router tab and see if you're on the good one. Your page does exist, right ? If you manually go to it (with a disabled middleware). Btw, I'm not sure that you need the `return`.

Comment: I can access the page with the middleware disabled, yes the page does exist.